# Why are bacon.js observables classified lazy sequences?

Tags: observablecollection, bacon.js

My understanding of lazy sequences is that they don't load data in memory until it's accessed by the program. So I can see how this would make sense if there was a large list of numbers, waiting to be consumed, but the sequence only pulled in the data from the producer when the iterator called the next method.

But observables append the item to themselves whenever the producer pushes it to them. So it's not like the sequence loads the data when consumer asks for it, it loads it whenever the producer sends it. So in what way are observables lazy?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 kinds of laziness in Bacon.js Observables:

1. Observables don't register to their underlying data source (for example, an AJAX fetch) until there is at least one Observer. This laziness practically gives you automatic resource management in the sense that connections to data sources are automatically opened and closed based on demand. Also if there are multiple Observers, only a single connection to the data source is used and the results are shared.
2. Observables don't evaluate the functions passed to `map`, `combine` etc until the value is actually used. So if you do expensive calculation in the function you give to `map` and only sample the stream once in a second, only those values will be actually evaluated.

What you don't get is backpressure management. So if you're data source, say observable `a`, produces infinite values sequentially, you can either

- process them immediately using `a.onValue`
- take 1000 first of them using `a.take(1000).onValue`
- take until some condition using `a.takeUntil((x) -> x > 1000)).onValue`

But you cannot affect the rate that the source produces the values, because Bacon.js provides no way to tell the source that "I'm interested in more values later, I'll tell you when". I've been thinking about adding something like this, but it would complicate matters a lot.

As the bottom line, I'd say that Bacon.js is not your ideal library for working with infinite lists, for instance, in the Haskell style. And AFAIK, neither is any other Javascript FRP lib.

Answer (score 0):

A lazy sequence is a sequence that evaluates its elements at the last time possible. What's useful about them is that you can pass the sequence around and even perform operations on it without evaluating its contents.

Since you don't evaluate the sequence, you can even create an infinite sequence; just make sure that you don't evaluate the whole of it. For example, the following Haskell program creates an infinite sequence of natural numbers, then lazily multiplies each element by 2, producing an infinite sequence of even numbers, then takes the first 5 elements, evaluating them (and only them):

```
take 5 (map (*2) [1..])
-- [2,4,6,8,10]
```

Basically, with lazy sequences and a set of functions that work over them, like `map`, you can write programs that create and process potentially infinite streams of data in a composable way.

Which, incidentally, is exactly what (functional) reactive programming is about. An observable can be seen as a potentially infinite stream of pairs `(value, timestamp)`. An operation on an observable, such as `map`, simply creates another stream based on the original one. Attaching a consumer to an observable evaluates the elements of it that "already happened", while leaving the rest un-evaluated.

For example, Bacon's `observable.map` can be implemented as a function that lazily applies a function to the 'value' part of the stream (again in Haskell):

```
map f = Prelude.map (\(value, tstamp) -> (f value, tstamp))
```

while `observable.delay` adds delay to the 'timestamp' part:

```
delay dt = Prelude.map (\(value, tstamp) -> (value, tstamp + dt))
```

where `Prelude.map` is just a regular "map" function over lazy sequences.

Hopefully I haven't confused you any further!